# Traverse an array and compare the current key value pair with next one php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, while-loop

Am trying to compare the key value pair of an array to compare the next key value pair to find the lower one value.if found the lower the higher one was to be unset and move forward.But am not getting the accuracy,what am doing wrong here,please suggest.Here is the code.
This is the array which is to be compared and evaluated.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [com_details] => Array
            (
                [spid] => 6

            )

        [distance] => 13.1 mi
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [com_details] => Array
            (
                [spid] => 6

            )

        [distance] => 66.2 mi
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [com_details] => Array
            (
                [spid] => 6

            )

        [distance] => 1.5 mi
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [com_details] => Array
            (
                [spid] => 7

            )

        [distance] => 188 mi
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [com_details] => Array
            (
                [spid] => 7

            )

        [distance] => 96.7 mi
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [com_details] => Array
            (
                [spid] => 7

            )

        [distance] => 3.1 mi
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [com_details] => Array
            (
                [spid] => 14

            )

        [distance] => 1.8 mi
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [com_details] => Array
            (
                [spid] => 14

            )

        [distance] => 228 mi
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [com_details] => Array
            (
                [spid] => 14

            )

        [distance] => 82.2 mi
    )

)
```

In the above array i need to compare those `com_details` whose spid is same and the distance is different,If the next or prev distance is small then the other one will be unset and move forward for next iteration.But am failing to this end point.

```
$l=0;
    do{
        $length = count($dispatch_locations1);
        if($length >= $l+1){
            if($dispatch_locations1[$l]['com_details']['spid'] == @$dispatch_locations1[$l+1]['com_details']['spid']){
               if($dispatch_locations1[$l]['distance'] > $dispatch_locations1[$l+1]['distance']){
                   unset($dispatch_locations1[$l]);
                   $l--;
                  $dispatch_locations1 =  array_values($dispatch_locations1);
               } else if($dispatch_locations1[$l]['distance'] < $dispatch_locations1[$l+1]['distance']){
                   unset($dispatch_locations1[$l+1]);
                   $l--;
                  $dispatch_locations1 =  array_values($dispatch_locations1);
      } else if($dispatch_locations1[$l]['distance'] == $dispatch_locations1[$l+1]['distance']){
                   unset($dispatch_locations1[$l+1]);
                   $l--;
                  $dispatch_locations1 =  array_values($dispatch_locations1);
      }
            }
        }
            $l++;
        } while ($l <= count($dispatch_locations1)+1);
    }
```

after the full iterations am getting this array which is somewhat wrong.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [com_details] => Array
            (
                [spid] => 6

            )

        [distance] => 1.5 mi
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [com_details] => Array
            (
                [spid] => 7

            )

        [distance] => 188 mi
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [com_details] => Array
            (
                [spid] => 14

            )

        [distance] => 1.8 mi
    )

)
```

In this result the second array distance returning is 188 which is wrong.

Please suggest what am doing wrong here.

Comment: I think your are trying to compare strings instead you need to compare floats.. so try to have some float typed key in your array or convert the distance to it

Comment: Also you can use usort instead of the do while http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: ok will try .. can u please suggest how to implement the usort.

Comment: I am on my phone will be at comp in 5 min

Comment: let me get your problem correctly.. you want to sort the array, first by spid and after by distance. am i right?

Comment: Sorting is not issue...i just want to choose the smallest distance value for a spid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify the Entire complex operation by abridging your code. The Code Snippet below demonstrates how but, before you begin, you may want to try & test it our yourself [here](https://eval.in/609345).

**THE SAMPLE ARRAY USED HERE FOR TESTING**

```
<?php

    $arrMain        = array(
        array(
            'com_details'   => array('spid'=> 6),
            'distance'      => "13.1mi",
        ),
        array(
            'com_details'   => array('spid'=> 6),
            'distance'      => "66.2 mi",
        ),
        array(
            'com_details'   => array('spid'=> 6),
            'distance'      => "1.5mi",
        ),
        array(
            'com_details'   => array('spid'=> 7),
            'distance'      => "188.0 mi",
        ),
        array(
            'com_details'   => array('spid'=> 7),
            'distance'      => "96.7 mi",
        ),
        array(
            'com_details'   => array('spid'=> 7),
            'distance'      => "3.1 mi",
        ),
        array(
            'com_details'   => array('spid'=> 14),
            'distance'      => "1.8 mi",
        ),
        array(
            'com_details'   => array('spid'=> 14),
            'distance'      => "228.0 mi",
        ),
        array(
            'com_details'   => array('spid'=> 14),
            'distance'      => "82.2 mi",
        ),
    );
```

**THE ALGORITHM**

```
<?php
    $arrSections    = array();

    // SORTING FUNCTION - USED TO SORT ARRAY VALUES BY "distance"
    // IN DESCENDING ORDER...
    function sortByField($prev, $next, $field="distance") {
        $prevVal = floatval(preg_replace("#[a-zA-Z\s\t]*#", "",$prev[$field]));
        $nextVal = floatval(preg_replace("#[a-zA-Z\s\t]*#", "",$next[$field]));
        return $prevVal - $nextVal;
    }

    // BUNDLE ARRAYS WITH SIMILAR spid INTO ONE GROUP
    // THUS CREATING A MULTI-DIMENSIONAL ARRAY WHOSE MAIN KEYS CORRESPOND TO
    // THE spid OF MEMBER ARRAYS IN THE GROUP. 
    foreach($arrMain as $iKey=>$subMain){
        $spID   = $subMain['com_details']['spid'];
        $strID  = $spID; 

        if(!array_key_exists($strID, $arrSections)) {
            $arrSections[$strID] = array();
        }
        $arrSections[$strID][] = $subMain;
    }

    // SORT THE ARRAY SIMPLY BY THE FIELD "distance" IN DESCENDING ORDER
    array_walk($arrSections, function (&$data) {
        usort($data, "sortByField");
    });

    // ARRAY THAT HOLDS THE DESIRED RESULT
    $arrFinal = array();

    // WE KNOW THAT ONLY THE FIRST ITEM IN THE ARRAY IS OF IMPORTANCE TO US
    // SO WE REMOVE ALL OTHER ITEMS EXCEPT THE 1ST...
    foreach($arrSections as $intKey=>&$section){
        array_splice($section, 1);
        $arrFinal[]   = $section[0];

    }
    var_dump($arrFinal);
```

**THE RESULT OF THE VAR_DUMP()**

```
    // var_dump($arrSections); PRODUCES:::
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'com_details' => 
            array (size=1)
              'spid' => int 6
          'distance' => string '1.5mi' (length=5)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          'com_details' => 
            array (size=1)
              'spid' => int 7
          'distance' => string '3.1 mi' (length=6)
      2 => 
        array (size=2)
          'com_details' => 
            array (size=1)
              'spid' => int 14
          'distance' => string '1.8 mi' (length=6)
```

Comment: Will implement this...one more thing...if we want to remove the extra array created i.e. `[6] => Array...[7] => Array...` etc

Comment: @SudhanshuSaxena The Code has been updated to reflect that...  the only  change made was at the bottom of the Code: the part that starts from **// ARRAY THAT HOLDS THE DESIRED RESULT** `$arrFinal = array();` till the end of the Code... Good Luck & Cheers.... ;-)

Comment: This one is the perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

If i get your problem correctly here is the code to solve that..

this code sorts array first by spid and than by distance:

```
<?php
usort($dispatch_locations1, function($a, $b) {
    if($a['com_details']['spid'] > $b['com_details']['spid']) {
        return 1;
    } elseif($a['com_details']['spid'] < $b['com_details']['spid']) {
        return -1;
    }

    return (floatval($a['distance']) < floatval($b['distance'])) ? -1 : 1;
});
?>
```